# How do I use Workbox Range Requests plugin with Vite PWA?

Tags: caching, video-streaming, progressive-web-apps, vite, workbox

My app is created with Vite and the Vite PWA plugin and I want to cache larger size video files in the cache for watching offline. Smaller videos <15MB cache fine, but currently larger videos fail offline because of the chunked 206 Range Requests. I'm hoping the Workbox Range Requests plugin will remedy this.

I am using the [`generateSW` strategy](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/workbox/generate-sw.html).

I can see the `workbox-range-requests` plugin is included as a dependency, but the Vite PWA config doesn't cover it's usage in the docs.

Here is the relevant part of my vite config:

```
// vite.config.js

VitePWA({
  ...
  workbox: {
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: /^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.subdomain\.domain\.com/,
        handler: 'NetworkFirst',
        options: {
          cacheName: 'media',
          expiration: {
            maxEntries: 500,
            maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2 // 2 years
          },
          cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [200]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I would prefer not to create a custom Service Worker and use `generateSW` via VitePWA config option, which seems should be possible. You can use the CacheableResponses plugin as defined above.

From the [relevant part of the workbox docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/serving-cached-audio-and-video/#the-problem), you can see that if you were writing your own service worker, a similar runtime caching pattern would be defined like this:

```
// sw.js

registerRoute(
  ({request}) => {
    const {destination} = request;

    return destination === 'video' || destination === 'audio'
  },
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'your-cache-name-here',
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [200]
      }),
      new RangeRequestsPlugin(),
    ],
  }),
);
```

You can see how the CacheableResponse constructor translates to the first `vite.config.js` example above (as a key directly under `options`, not nested in `options.plugins`), but not sure what to do with Range Requests constructor.

I'm thinking something like this should work:

```
VitePWA({
  ...
  workbox: {
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: /^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.subdomain\.domain\.com/,
        handler: 'NetworkFirst',
        options: {
          cacheName: 'media',
          expiration: {
            maxEntries: 500,
            maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2 // 2 years
          },
          cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [200]
          },
          rangeRequests: {
            statuses: [206, 416]
          }
          // OR
          rangeRequests: {}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Not winning here. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually really simple Boolean property:

```
VitePWA({
  ...
  workbox: {
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: /^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.subdomain\.domain\.com/,
        handler: 'NetworkFirst',
        options: {
          cacheName: 'media',
          expiration: {
            maxEntries: 500,
            maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2 // 2 years
          },
          cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [200]
          },
          rangeRequests: true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

For "vite-plugin-pwa" ^0.16.4